# Remover Detalhes do C# WebBrowser Imprimir

Tags: c#

[image: Detalhes de impressão]

Assim como na imagem, preciso remover esses detalhes no canto da página e colocar uma descrição no canto de baixo da página será possível?

Estou fazendo uma impressão assim:

wb.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();

Comment: São informações insuficientes, coloque como chegou no processo de um forma geral e como colocar um texto no rodapé?

Answer (score 1):

Tente dar uma olhada na utilização de de @media print via css.
Segue um link com uns exemplos bacanas sobre o assunto: http://taylorlopes.com/?p=1855

Basicamente você precisa configurar as áreas que você deseja imprimir:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Not Print</title>
      <style type="text/css">
          @media print { 
              .notprint { visibility:hidden; } 
          }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <strong>Isto vai ser impresso!</strong>
      <div class="notprint">
          Já isto, não será impresso!
      </div> 
      Aqui também será impresso!             
    </body>
</html>
```

Fonte do exemplo: Taylor Lopes (link acima)